# Laravel Polymorphic Relationship trouble with Camel Case

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my polymorphic relationship, Laravel automatically converts my CamelCase id to an underscore. So when I try to get $store->product, I receive Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Products.location_id'.

My relationship looks like this.

```
Class Store() {
    public function product() {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Product', 'locationId');
    }
}
```

Is there a way to not convert to underscore from CamelCase.

EDIT
It appears it's actually adding "_id" to the end of the locationId. Any idea how to restrict/stop this?

Comment: try to use two arguments for relation, ie `return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Product', 'locationId', 'id');`

Comment: No, luck. Also I realzied the problem is that it's automatically adding "_id" onto the end, not actually breaking up the CamelCase. Any idea how to stop this?

Comment: i wonder if you changed your database to conform with the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations). and yes, it actually adding `_id` to `morph` relations. it's a pretty default behavior for laravel - like it assume foreign key as `referenceModel_id`. yep, the [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2069) had the code to add `_id`.

Comment: Thanks for the source link. At the very least I can overwrite it. And there's another app that uses the database so I don't really want to change it too much.

Comment: ah well, the answer below had better approach - to not modify the code..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you aren't going to follow the standard naming structure, the [`morphOne`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_morphOne) method accepts additional parameters that allow you to override it.

```
public function morphOne($related, $name, $type = null, $id = null, $localKey = null)
{
    $instance = new $related;

    list($type, $id) = $this->getMorphs($name, $type, $id);

    $table = $instance->getTable();

    $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();

    return new MorphOne($instance->newQuery(), $this, $table.'.'.$type, $table.'.'.$id, $localKey);
}
```

Without knowing your database structure, all I can tell you is that the 4th argument allows you to override the id. That's where you put `locationId`.

Comment: so, basically like `$this->morphOne('App\Models\Product', 'location', null, 'locationId', null)` ?

Comment: That can work. Did you name the type `location_type` in your table?

Comment: I did. It works for the morphOne. Thanks  a bunch Thomas. Any chance you can give me a hint on how to do the same with the morphTo? It could just be a general mistake, but I'm struggling to make it work.

Comment: Nvm, I got it. Thanks again Thomas!

Comment: Hi. I know it’s been a while, but how did you get morphTo to work?

Answer (score 2):

For the morphTo method, you can pass these parameters

`$this->morphTo($name = null, $type = null, $id = null, $ownerKey = null);`

where

```
$name = foreign table columnable_type
$id   = foreign table columnable_id
$ownerKey = the primary model id
```